# login with google/facebook using aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Friends I am new to this AWS Cognito World. I have small question
I want to offer users to Sign Up / Sign In using Google/Facebook.Is that possible to call AWS API and invoke AWS Cognito to perform these sign up activities using AWS? and then have JWT session/token?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot have AWS handle logging in through Facebook or Google for your end users. You can introduce the Facebook and Google SDKs into your application, have users sign in through the appropriate Facebook/Google APIs, and pass those tokens to Cognito Federated Identities to obtain AWS credentials.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/external-identity-providers.html